# What does "beyond giddy" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I recently came across the following sentence:

> Their bond was that of two best friends who were beyond giddy to be getting married.

What does `beyond giddy` mean in this context?

Comment: Even giddier than "giddy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Giddy](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/giddy): (M-W)

> - feeling or showing great happiness and joy
> - to feel extremely excited.
>
>   - The news made him positively giddy.
>   - He was giddy with delight.

- the expression refers to their overexcitement to the prospect of getting married.